# Modx Revolution в админке не видны файлы, загруженные через ftp

Tags: modx

MODX Revolution 2.7.1-pl загружаю файлы в директорию сайта на сервер, в админке в filesystem их нет. Как можно исправить?

Comment: права на файлы смотрели?

Comment: Да, права у всех файлов выставлены под пользователя, от которого работает сайт

Comment: В какую директорию загружаете? а если в другую? У пользователя достаточно прав на просмотр? для его группы не выставлены ли какие-то кастомные права? нет ли какого-либо нештатного плагина, который "перехватывает" раздачу прав?

Comment: У пользователя все права, другой директории нет, но веб сервер настроен, что у сайта два домена и рабочая директория одна